# Finding the order of a group and isomorphism class from the presentation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let a group be given by $G = \{<a,b> | ab = ba^2, a^3=b^2 = e\}$ where e is the identity. 
How do I show that the order of G is 6 and determine the isomorphism class.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*At the time of writing, there was another answer simply stating that this is the dihedral group on $6$ elements.*

Observe that $G$ has at most $6$ elements, since any product of the symbols $a$ and $b$ can be simplified into one of the following six forms by repeatedly applying the rules of the group presentation:
$$
e,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b.
$$
On the other hand, there are at least six elements, since $a$ has order $3$ the number of elements is a multiple of $3$, and similarly since $b$ has order $2$ the number of elements is a multiple of $2$. Thus there are exactly $6$ elements.

Finally, observe that the group is non-abelian, since $ab^2$ and $ab$ are distinct means that $ab^2\not=b^2a$. There is only one non-abelian group of order $6$, the symmetric group on $3$ elements.

An explicit bijection is given by sending $a$ to any $3$-cycle and $b$ to any $2$-cycle.

---

Regarding the drive-by downvote(s), I assume it is due to confusion regarding the dual answers involving the symmetric group on the one hand, and the dihedral group on the other - which appear (on the surface) to be two different groups. In fact, both answers are correct: the unique non-abelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to **both** the symmetric group $S_3$, and the dihedral group with six elements.

Let me explain what is going on here in more detail, since it is actually quite nice. For any natural number $n\in\mathbb N$, we have the following concrete representation of the dihedral group. Take $n$ points equally spaced around the unit circle in the plane. Then the dihedral group of order $2n$ is the group of [rigid symmetries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation) of these $n$ points. It consists of rotations (by multiples of $2\pi/n$) and reflections. On the other hand, the symmetric group $S_n$ consists of **all** ways of permuting these $n$ points - and in particular, includes the rigid symmetries as a special case. When $n=4$ and higher we can find permutations that don't come from rigid symmetries: for instance, the permutation leaving one side of a square fixed and interchanging the corners of the side does not arise from a rigid symmetry, since it does not preserve distances between the pairs of corners. But when $n=3$, a magical thing happens: **all** permutations arise from rigid symmetries! Thus the symmetric and dihedral groups coincide in the special case we are considering.

Comment: Would be great if downvoters explained why they downvoted, as this has happened twice now on a perfectly complete and comprehensive answer!

Comment: Your argument is a bit flawed. The first part shows that $G$ has order at most $6$, but then $a^3=1$ only implies the order of $a$ divides $3$. So, to finish the argument, it is better to simply point out that $S_3$ satisfies the presentation, therefore the group must be $S_3$. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @verret actually, $a^3=e$ *does* imply that the order of $a$ is $3$, since the only other option $a=e$ leads to a group that does not have the given presentation (cyclic group on two elements, specifically generated by $b$ in this case).

Comment: Even your latest comment is a bit unclear. If we take the cyclic group of order $2$, generated by $b$, and $a$ the identity in that group, then that DOES satisfy the presentation. (In the sense that all the relations hold.) Now of course that doesn't mean that this is the group defined by the presentation, just that it's a quotient of it.

Of course, you are right that the presentation defines $S_3$, but a minimal argument goes as follow: first argue that the group has order at most $6$ (as you did), then show that $S_3$ does satisfy the presentation. That's it.

Comment: Consider for example the group $\langle a,b\mid a^3=1,ba^2b^{-1}=1\rangle$. Note that $a$ does not have order $3$ in this group, in spite of the $a^3=1$ relation. What is the difference between this example and the one in the question that allows you to conclude directly from the presentation that $a$ has order $3$?

Comment: To be perfectly clear. I am not saying that $a$ does not have order $3$ in the current question, it does. I am just saying that (1) this cannot be read off directly from the presentation, as you somehow do in your answer, and (2) it does not matter anyway, it is not necessary in a proof.

Comment: @verret I get your point regarding shortening the argument, however I don't believe my argument is flawed. Notice my comment 3 says "... leads to a group that does not *have* the given presentation", which is different than how you interpreted as if I wrote "... leads to a group that does not **satisfy** the given presentation". It amounts to the difference between saying two groups are equal vs one is a subgroup of the other. Your example illustrates both of our points - and perhaps could be made more explicit by invoking the definition of a presentation as a quotient of a free group.

Comment: I still think the way you wrote your argument is more or less circular. You claim very early on that $a$ has order $3$. Why is that true? Through discussion in the comments, you argue that, otherwise, $a$ would be the identity, and then the group would be cyclic of order $2$. Why is the group not cyclic of order $2$, given that that group DOES satisfy the presentation? Well, because the presentation actually defines $S_3$. Right, and why is that true? Well because $a$ has order $3$, so $3$ divides the order of the group, as in your original answer!

Comment: In other words, I think it's preferable to say that $a$ has order $3$ because the group is $S_3$, and not the other way around! (And of course, at this point, there's actually no point in bringing up the order of $a$ at all.) Here's a challenge: try to fill in the missing details in your claim that $a$ has order $3$ in your answer. I think you'll find that you essentially have to prove that the group is $S_3$ (or at least has order $6$) along the way, which shows that your proof is circular.

Comment: @verret the proof is not circular, although I do agree with your assessment that my proof can be more direct